# Configure connectionString to use SQL Server instead of SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, full-text-search, connection-string, full-text-indexing

**Problem**

I have a webproject that uses Fulltext-search, that I imported to a new computer (virtual machine).

I get a warning, when opening the website in Visual Studio, saying:

"*The Web project xxx requires SQL Server Express, which is not installed on this computer. The recommended database engine for Microsoft Visual Studio is SQL Server LocalDB Express...*"

[image: Visual Studio warning]

**Old computer setup:**

- SQL Server Express with Advanced Services (I think it was 2012).
- Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate installed.

**New computer (VM) setup:**

- SQL Server Enterprise 2012 (from DreamSpark).
- Visual Studio 2014 Professional.

**How i'm trying to resolve it:**

I tried to modify the connectionString, but I couldn't find the right SQL db engine in Advanced Properties:

[image: Modify Connection]

[image: Advanced Properties]

[image: Available database engines]

How do I get the right engine to show up here?

Comment: . or localhost resolves to the local computer. You could try selecting that (just . not .\SQLExpressx64ADV) as a first option. I'm not sure what "DreamSpark" is, but if you've got the full enterprise SQL Server installed then pop into the SQL Server Management Studio app from the start menu and retrieve the name of the locally installed instance from there as a 2nd option.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know, that ". " meant localhost. I managed to get it to connect to the db using a workaround. I attached the .mdf file in SSMS. In Visual Studio, when I modified the connectionString, I chose "MS SQL Server" instead of "MS SQL Server Database File". I then copied the data source string from "Advanced Properties" and inserted into the web.config file.
"Dreamspark" is a Microsoft service with free software for students.

Comment: @Alex Read: It does not work, if I just select localhost. It will then give me an error telling me that "user instance login flag is not supported for this version of SQL Server".
I seems that I HAVE to select "MS SQL Server" as datasource in the "Modify Connection" window before the right SQL Server engine is available. It is not possible to write anything in the "data source" field inside the "Advanced Properties" window. It is only possible to choose available engines from the dropdown-menu.
It is working now, so I will leave it at that. Thanks for your answer though.